# Where do I put $this->request->headers('Content-Type', 'application/json');

Tags: php, json, kohana, content-type, kohana-3

I'm trying to change the content-type to application/json in Kohana. I put this in an action in my controller:

```
$this->request->headers('Content-Type', 'application/json');
$this->content = json_encode($json_data);
```

The request however, has still the text/html content-type.

Where should I put `$this->request->headers('Content-Type', 'application/json');`   ?

Answer (score 10):

To elaborate on Claudio's answer, yes you need to set the response header, not the request, like so

```
$this->response->headers('Content-Type','application/json');
```

Also, I'm not sure how you've implemented your controller, but it looks like it may be a template controller based on

```
$this->content = json_encode($json_data);
```

If you are using a template controller, make sure you set auto_render to FALSE.

Finally, set the response body with your json data

```
$this->response->body(json_encode($json_data));
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to edit the *response* headers.

http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/api/Response#headers

Answer (score 1):

The OP asked where to put it. If you're using a controller that extends Controller_Template, like I am, I just added Andrew Schmid's code example to my base controller's after() method (before parent::after()) and it worked great.

So:

```
Controller_Your_Controller extends Controller_Template {

   // Your controller actions

   public function after()
   {
       // Set the response content-type here
       $this->response->headers('Content-Type','application/json');
       parent::after();
   }
}
```